# Oracle Spatial geometry transformation from one SRID to another and back doesn't result in same coordinates

Tags: oracle, spatial, coordinate-transformation

I am doing the following transformation from SRID 4326 to SRID 21781:

```
select SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE(8.554697094, 47.355028826, NULL),NULL,NULL),21781) geometrie from dual;
```

Which results in the correct coordinates: **684237.530726634 / 245289.311003668**

But when I transform this back to SRID 4326:

```
select SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,21781,SDO_POINT_TYPE(684237.530726634, 245289.311003668, NULL),NULL,NULL),4326) geometrie from dual;
```

The resulting coordinates are completely wrong: **8.19567132311754 / 0.232474117334404**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get `684319.949, 245508.076` from your first query, and `8.55356521, 47.3530719` from your second one. If I plug my answer from the first one into the second one instead, I get `8.55469711, 47.3550288` - which is close to what you started with. Don't know what precision is expected. This is 11gR2, and I don't use this or know what to make of it, but thought it might be interesting...

Comment: Meant to say this is 11.2.0.3; what version are you getting this on? There may be bugs in the this area, looking at MOS.

Comment: Your transformation is correct! Yes, it could be a bug. I am using 10.2.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to 11.2.0.2.0, now the result is correct. It is a bug in versions < 11.2.0.1.0.